# NetSuite : FreeMarker/BFO Images Cutting Off at Page Break

Tags: html, css, netsuite, freemarker, bfo

I have a Rich Text Field inside NetSuite with multiple images. Unfortunately, the images that don't fit on the first page/same page, are NOT getting pushed down to a second page after generating the Advanced PDF. Instead, BFO just cuts-off the image at page break. Any suggestions on how I can address this issue? It was recommended that I put my data into tables, as well as use `page-break-inside`, but the same image still cuts-off at the page break.

Advanced PDF:

```
<table page-break-inside="auto">
 <tr>
   <td>${result.custevent_images?replace('&amp;', '&#38;')?replace('">', '"/>')}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

NetSuite Rich Text Field:

```
<table page-break-inside="auto">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img1...>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img2...>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img3...>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Having this same exact problem with a Table as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to split the images. For good measure, I also had to encode the '&' as well as the closing '/' tags that get removed by NetSuite after the field is edited.

```
 <table style="width:100%;" page-break-before="always">
     <#list result.custevent_images?split("<br />") as x>
                <tr>
                    <td>${x?replace('&amp;', '&#38;')?replace('">', '"/>')}</td>
                </tr>
    </#list>
 </table>
```